# C++ template specialization question

Tags: c++

I'm trying to implement a generic toString() function that would work on all types. All our internal classes derive from Abstract which includes a signature for toString(). In other words, all our internal classes have in some form, a toString method.

The problem is, the primitive types (int, char, double..) don't have a native toString function. But we do have a utility function that calls the lexical_cast to give back the string value of the primitive. We don't want a whole bunch of if statements depending  So I'm trying to create a templated utility class that would do the job.

My first hack at this is the below:

```
    template<class T>
    class ObjectToString {
    public:
        string objectToString(T value) {
            iil::stringUtils::StringSp ret(stringUtils::valueToString<T>(value));
            return ret;
        }
    };

    template<>
    class ObjectToString <Abstract<T>*> {
    public:
        iil::stringUtils::StringSp objectToString(Abstract<T>* value) {
            return iil::stringUtils::StringSp(new std::string("AAAA"));
        }
    };
```

The problem now is, since Abstract is a templated class, it needs the template value T. I have no idea how to set that. Could anyone advise?

Comment: sounds like you guys implement Java

Answer (score 7):

How about simply providing a specialization for lexical_cast?

```
template<> string lexical_cast(Abstract* obj)
{
  return obj->toString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Isn't your problem much simpler? On all Abstract objects you know what to do, so all you need is to provide overloaded functions for built-in types:

```
string getAsString(Abstract *obj)
{
  return obj->toString();
}

string getAsString(int x)
{
  return intToStr(x);
}

string getAsString(double x)
{
  return doubleToStr(x);
}
```

etc, where you implement intToStr() and doubleToStr() as appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

You just don't think in C++ way. C++ already **has** "toString" that is called `operator<<` to `std::ostream`. You need to implement it for your classes.

And if you want to support inheritence, do this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
#include <string>

class streamable {
public:
    virtual void stream(std::ostream &) const = 0;
};
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out,streamable const &obj)
{
    obj.stream(out);
    return out;
}

// Now anything derived from streamable can be written to std::ostream
// For example:

class bar : public streamable {
    int x;
    int y;
public:
    bar(int a,int b) : x(a),y(b){}
    virtual void stream(std::ostream &out) const { out<<x<<":"<<y; }
};

int main()
{
    bar b(1,3);
    std::cout<< b << std::endl;

    // and converted to string
    std::string str=boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(b);

    std::cout<< str <<std::endl;
}
```

This **is** C++ way, and as you can see you have `boost::lexical_cast` for free.

EDIT for your case:

```
template<typename T>
class Abstract {
public:
    virtual void stream(std::ostream &) const = 0;
};

template<typename T>
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out,Abstract<T> const &obj)
{
    obj.stream(out);
    return out;
}
```

Now if you don't like boost::lexical_cast, implement `string_cast` as simple as

```
template<typename T>
std::string string_cast(T const &obj)
{
   std::ostringstram ss;
   ss<<obj;
   return ss.str();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This has been dealt with at length by [Matthew Wilson](http://www.blogger.com/profile/08032564940029177259) in the form of *shims*, as described in [this Dr Dobb's article](http://www.ddj.com/article/printableArticle.jhtml?articleID=184401689&dept_url=/cpp/), and the books [Imperfect C++](http://www.imperfectcplusplus.com/) and [Extended STL](http://www.extendedstl.com/). They underlie the technology that allow the [FastFormat](http://www.fastformat.org/) and [Pantheios](http://www.pantheios.org/) libraries to deal with argument types generically.